# How to use local X/Y/Z.png tiles from OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

OpenLayers 3 Local Tiles
I need to use local tiles. Please help.

I have tried this

```
var map = new ol.Map({

    layers : [ layers['vworld'], vectorLayer ],
    interactions : ol.interaction.defaults({
        shiftDragZoom : false
    }).extend([ new ol.interaction.DragRotateAndZoom() ]),
    target : 'map',

    view : new ol.View({
        // center: ol.proj.transform([getLongi, getLati ], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        center : ol.proj.fromLonLat([ 127.5, 36 ]),
        zoom : 7, minZoom : 6, maxZoom : 19
    })
});

var layers = {};
layers['vworld'] = new ol.layer.Tile({
    title : 'VWorld Gray Map', visible : true, type : 'base',
    source : new ol.source.XYZ({
        url : 'H:/tile/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
    })
});
```

Not allowed to load local resource: `file:///H:/tile/7/110/48.png` <- I'm getting an error.. From Chrome

The tile is located at H: `/tile/bla~/bla~/bla~.png`
It is a world map, there are many folders in the tile folder, and there are many PNG files in it.

The `xyz` value provided by openlayer is different from the tile I have. What should I do?

Comment: You can only access file:/// resources if your html is also on file:///

Comment: I do not understand. What should I do .. ?? Help me

Comment: Internet websites are not allowed to access files on your local drives.  If your data is on a local drive your html file must also be on a local drive and must be run from there for example `file:///H:/maps/mymap.html`

Comment: Where should openlayer3 and tile be on the same drive?

Comment: Mike, please help me.

Comment: Your main html must be on local drive, but you could use any of them.  To access something which is `file:///` it must itself be `file:///` (any local drive) and not `http://`   But you can access `http://` and `https://` from `file:///` so your html can still include `ol.js` and other scripts from the web.